# How to retrieve the values from a post request function django views. DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a function that makes a queryset when data from my frontend is posted.
This viewset is using a serializer of combined models.

On my index page on the fronted I have a treeview filter and this view loads the query to
a config page. I need to access the event id's after this query is made to be passed to a separate task on the backend for polling.

However I cannot access the data in this function. How would I get retrieve this query and filter on the data? right now I can't print the queryset to see its structure.

**Edit:**

I can see the response payload now and the structure is as follows

```
[{"id":395,"event":{"id":175,"start_time":"28-10-20","sport_id":"9","event_id":"1576232279920003","event_name":"Botic Van de Zandschulp vs Benjamin Bonzi","status":"open"},"market":{"id":198,"market_id":"1576232286670003","market_name":"Moneyline","status":"open","volume":50.4951,"is_ip":"False","event":175},"bettriggers":null,"stakes":null,"userstakes":null,"order":null,"runner_id":"1576232286740003","name":"Botic Van de Zandschulp","back_odds":1.62893,"lay_odds":1.68028},{"id":396,"event":{"id":175,"start_time":"28-10-20","sport_id":"9","event_id":"1576232279920003","event_name":"Botic Van de Zandschulp vs Benjamin Bonzi","status":"open"},"market":{"id":198,"market_id":"1576232286670003","market_name":"Moneyline","status":"open","volume":50.4951,"is_ip":"False","event":175},"bettriggers":null,"stakes":null,"userstakes":null,"order":null,"runner_id":"1576232286780103","name":"Benjamin Bonzi","back_odds":2.47,"lay_odds":2.59}]

class CombinedViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, 
                   mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                   mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                   viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    permission_classes = [IsMeOrReadOnly]
    queryset = Runner.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CombinedSerializer

    @action(detail=False, methods=['POST','GET])
    def loaditem(self, request):
        keys = request.data['keys']
        queryset = []
        for xx in keys:
            if xx['time_key'] is None:
                if xx['event_key'] is None:
                    queryset.extend(Runner.objects.filter(event__sport_id=xx['sport_key']))
                else:
                    queryset.extend(Runner.objects.filter(event__event_id=xx['event_key']))
            else:
                date_str = xx['time_key']
                datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d-%m-%y')
                queryset.extend(Runner.objects.filter(event__start_time__date=datetime_obj, event__sport_id=xx['sport_key']))

        serializer_class = CombinedSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer_class.data)
```

What my end goal is to pass in the filtered list of event_id's from load item function to a backend celery task

```
@shared_task(bind=True, base=QueueOnce, once={'graceful': True})
def get_events(self):

    api = get_client()

    sports = api.reference_data.get_sports()
    logger.warning(f'GET EVENTS task has been called now')

    events = api.market_data.get_selected_events(event_ids=['2323','34343','1576232279920003','etc'])
```

This is what my serializer looks like

```
class CombinedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    event = EventSerializer()
    market = MarketSerializer()
    bettriggers = BetTriggersSerializer()
    stakes = StakesSerializer()
    userstakes = UserStakesSerializer()
    order = OrderStakesSerializer()
    
    class Meta:
       model = Runner
       fields= '__all__'
```

Frontend code for posting data

```
  load_item: function (event) {
          if(this.value == null) return;
          var len = this.value.length;
          var req_key = [];

          for (var x=0; x<len; x++) {
            var str = ''+this.value[x];
            var tmp_arr = str.split('@');
            var sport_key = null;
            var time_key = null;
            var event_key = null;
            switch(tmp_arr.length) {
              case 1:
                sport_key = tmp_arr[0];
                break;
              case 2:
                event_key = tmp_arr[1];
                break;
              case 3:
                time_key = tmp_arr[2];
                sport_key = tmp_arr[1];
                break;
            }
            req_key.push({sport_key:sport_key, event_key:event_key, time_key:time_key});
          }
          var vobj = this
          this.$axios.post('/api/combined/loaditem/', {
            keys : req_key
          })
          .then(function (response) {
            vobj.$store.dispatch('load_runner', response.data)
            vobj.$router.push('/configuration')
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            //currentObj.output = error;
            console.log(error)
          });
        },
```

Comment: can you post the response you're getting and the URL you are trying

Comment: @yovelcohen I've just updated my question with the code  and the response payload from the frontend